Emphasizing OP's lack of background when they ask unclear questions?
I don't think this question is unclear at all:

How can someone prove that he knows you more than yourself?
I know about personalities of some people, but I cannot prove it through valid reasons. How do you know if a person really does understand you more than yourself as an individual?

Well, I think I understand your perspective. If OP know a model of personality and ask questions based on that, then their understanding will improve significantly, and not only they can find the correct term to describe what they feel, but also be able to ask clear questions here.
But in OP's perspective, it may not be unclear why their question is unclear:

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think in their perspective they are doing exactly what it suggests, to their best. Of course their best is not enough, but telling them to do the thing they have already done will only confuse them. I suggest for this type of question we should encourage OP to read textbooks, or else they will never find the necessary vocabulary to describe their problem.
For those who have known me enough, I think this is the one big problem of this site, beside lacking of user base. But it is easy to fix if we can have perspective-taking and aware of our illusion of transparency. We may also want to use the I-message to talk with them.

+1 It's a good idea @Ooker.  Do you have some verbiage to suggest to modify the current close message?

@ArnonWeinberg AFAIK, the "unclear" close reason is a standard SE close reason that can't be modified though.

@ArnonWeinberg I don't think we need to modify the close notice; a comment will help. See my answer below

Here are some canned comments I would use in each case:

Unclear question:

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately while it is possible that you may see your question as objective and answerable, it still contains too much assumptions that only you can understand, and thus is still unclear for us. I suggest you to start with an introductory textbook about ____________________. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure you will gain more insight just after reading a few pages.

Diagnostic question:

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately while it is possible that you may see your question as objective and answerable, it still contains too much assumptions that only a trained therapist can handle. If you can't book one now, I suggest you to start with an introductory book about _______________. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure you will gain more insight just after reading a few pages. See more: Are question about identifying (potential) disorder based on behaviour on topic?.

More than one question asked:

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately it seems that your post has a lot of questions, and the site is built to answer one question at a time. I suggest you to start with an introductory textbook about ____________________. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure many of your questions will be answered just after reading a few pages.


Code to import in SE-AutoReviewComments:
###[Q] Unclear question 
Unfortunately while it is possible that you may see your question as objective and answerable, it still contains too much assumptions that only you can understand, and thus is still unclear for us. I suggest you to start with an introductory textbook about **_______________**. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure you will gain more insight after just reading a few pages.

###[Q] Diagnostic question 
Unfortunately while it is possible that you may see your question as objective and answerable, it still contains too much assumptions that only a trained therapist can handle. If you can't book one now, I suggest you to start with an introductory book about **_______________**. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure you will gain more insight just after reading a few pages. See more: [Are question about identifying (potential) disorder based on behaviour on topic?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2391/12937). 

###[Q] More than one question asked
Welcome to the site! Unfortunately it seems that your post has a lot of questions, and the site is built to answer one question at a time. I suggest you to start with an introductory textbook about **_______________**. Many of them are very easy to understand and fascinating. I'm sure many of your questions will be answered just after reading a few pages.


Availability to textbooks, or even libraries is not universal. There are SE users who's main access to written knowledge is only their cell phone. So it's better if messages don't assume a certain level of affluence if they can avoid it.

Unfortunately, I think that the only way to do it is reading textbooks, given my experience on this site, before and after reading them.

This is still a problem now. We have a swade of newcomers dumping questions with little or no structure to support high quality questions. Also it is demoralising trying to engage with them and to indicate that their question is based on false assumptions when they throw your suggestions back in your face most of the time. People want to vent and not really learn and improve their awareness is my impression.

I think this particular question is an example of an XY problem. The OP is asking "how can someone prove (they know someone more than that person knows themself)?".
They haven't in any way established that it makes sense to do so, they haven't set up a context for this interaction to take place, they haven't defined what it means to "know" someone, etc.
Otherwise, the question is unclear and should be closed as such.
